# Javascript to replace among the DOMs

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code:

```
 var contents; 
 window.onload = function(){
 contents = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
 console.log(contents);
  };
```

It gets the content of the body. Now I want to replace `*` with `<span>*</span>`. How should I approach this?

I want to use Javascript and not jQuery.

Comment: Regular expression i suppose

Comment: @lavrik horrible idea.

Comment: Why @BenjaminGruenbaum?

Comment: @lavrik would be slow and very error prone (* in tag attributes). It's parsing HTML with regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For not replacing the entire HTML (*really bad attitude*), we can do fast manipulation with elements:

```
var specialTags = ["head", "script", "style"].join("|"),
    re = new RegExp("^(?:" + specialTags + ")$", "i");

for (var els = document.getElementsByTagName("*"), i = els.length; i--;) {
    var el = els[i];

    if (re.test(el.tagName))
        continue;

    for (var j = 0, childs = el.childNodes, lj = childs.length; j < lj; j++) {
        var child = childs[j];
        if (child.nodeType === 3 && child.nodeValue.indexOf("*") > -1) {
            var segments = child.nodeValue.split("*");
            for (var k = 0, lk = segments.length; k < lk; k++) {
                el.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(segments[k]), child);
                if (k < lk - 1) {
                    var span = document.createElement("span");
                    span.className = "red";
                    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode("*"));
                    el.insertBefore(span, child);
                }
            }
            el.removeChild(child);
        }
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/GBqkb/

Comment: Beat me to it. Although my solution used a `TreeWalker` this is close enough.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum `TreeWalker` is easy to use, though this one should be supported by more browsers.

Comment: `TreeWalker`s work on every browser since IE9, and even Microsoft are dropping support for IE8 next month :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks lord! `:)`

Comment: would you please explain special_tags a little bit more and totally go over your suggestion...thanks much